# Inflation or CPI times CURRENCY/DOLLAR rate?

Tags: inflation, international-economics, foreign-exchange

Is there a database which follows the inflation or cpi MULTIPLIED by the forex rate. In order to calculate the change in cost of living around the world relative to ONE, NORMALISED base currency, preferably a strong currency in the forex markets.

For example, Turkish inflation is 74% but Turkish lira has halved. SO against the dollar, life in Turkey  experienced DEFLATION of 13%

Comment: You may want to look into purchasing power or purchasing power parity (PPP).

Comment: But if you really just want CPI multiplied by an exchange rate, I doubt this will be available because it can be done with a one liner in most languages, provided you download the two series (CPI and USDTRY in your case).